# What does Harrow Bloodline give me?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, powers, sorcerer, bloodline

I was looking through the bloodlines available to sorcerers in Pathfinder and found the Harrow (Tarrot) bloodline. It's effects sound cool but **Invoke the Harrow's**

> ... +4 enhancement bonus to the ability score associated with the [drawn] card's suit...

leaves a bit open to interpretation. Like Strength and Lovers are pretty straight forward, but what about the other Major arcanas **AND** the lowly Swords, Cups, Wands and Pentacles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need more information on the Harrow Deck to play any kind of harrow character.  See [the downloadable instructions for the harrow deck on paizo.com](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8yt3?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Harrow-Deck), and consider reading the [Harrow Handbook](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/The_Harrow_Handbook) and other sources to understand what it is before just choosing it as a character optimization option.

[Harrow](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Harrow) is NOT identical to Tarot.  Here are the Harrow suites and what abilities they map to.

- Hammer - Strength
- Key - Dexterity
- Shield - Constitution
- Book - Intelligence
- Star - Wisdom
- Crown - Charisma